# Perform action at each time firefox is started

Tags: firefox-addon

I am working on the firefox addon. In this i have to add the spefic code that runs each time the firefox is loaded. So where should i write this block of code.

Which event should i add and should it be in overlay.js file?

If my information is incomplete, please specify what else should i post here.

Thanks
BHAVIK GOYAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute this in the main overlay:

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function() {
  // code to run at startup
}, false );
```

Comment: This will run every time a new window is opened, not just at application startup.